# IdentityServer4 how to store and renew tokens in authorization code flow

Tags: access-token, identityserver4

I am looking for the best approach to work with the IdentityServer4 autorization code flow.

My apps system is quite ordinary: I have an MVC client, a WebAPI and the IS. I also use AJAX to request the API from the client side. So I need the access token on the client side to put it into the authorization header.

Is it good idea to store access token in the cookies?

Do I need self-contained or reference token (it is about security, I suppose)?

What is the best approach to renew when it was expired?

I thought about the two strategies:

1. Update access token when the first 401 status code was recieved. Can be the problem cause I send more than 1 query to the API and I need to synchronized them and recall the first one (to get result);
2. Every time before API calling call the MVC client method with GetTokenAsync, check the expire time and get or update and get access token. Seems cheating, cause I need to call the MVC client every time when I want to call the API.

Could you help me to find the best way?

Comment: By saying this - " I also use AJAX to request the API from the client side", do you mean that you have a separate client (some angular, react, vue or whatever client side application), or you mean the MVC client?

Comment: I mean the MVC client. I use the MVC controller to get different views and after use js http client, like axios , to get data from the API. It is the reason I work with authorization code flow

Answer (score 0):

"Is it good idea to store access token in the cookies?"

No, not with the authorization code flow. If you are using an MVC web application you should find a way to store tokens in some kind of datastore away from the browser. All the MVC application should administer is a cookie to access future MVC endpoints (that will make subsequent calls to Identity Server with the appropriate access token in the datastore).

"Do I need self-contained or reference token (it is about security, I suppose)?"

That's all up to you and what you think is best for your use cases. If you'd like to see the information in the access token and skip the extra backend call for validation then use reference tokens. Strategy 2 requires you to use self-contained tokens so that you can check the expiry.

"Could you help me to find the best way?

I don't know if I can give the "best" way, but I'd probably go with strategy 2 and use self-contained tokens.

EDIT: If you wanted to use "axios , to get data from the API" then I would suggest using the implicit flow which has no concept of a refresh token. In this case, leaving it in the cookie should be OK.